# Set the display-settings tag in order

Tags: discussion, tags

The [display-settings](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/display-settings) tag is used in a pretty generic way by people who want to change something related to their display, whether it's monitor arrangement, GPU tuning, window manager decorations, etc. As currently used, the tag is too ambiguous to be useful.

Is this tag useful at all? I think we need at least a disambiguation campaign, replacing this tag by a more appropriate one in each case. What tags are likely target of the disambiguation? Should the tag be kept at all, and if so what is it supposed to mean?

Comment: When was `nvidia-settings` called `display-settings`? I don't remember that at all and I'm 90% sure it was already called `nvidia-settings` when I first saw it back when I was using SuSe in ~03-04, long before this site was created.

Comment: @terdon I may be misremembering then. I thought there used to be a utility commonly installed as `/usr/bin/display-settings`, but I can't find any trace of it, so I must be mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

I would say it's not much helpful. I cannot imagine there are users who specifically answer to questions about display settings, and avoid answering other questions about displays.

If there is really need of a tag, I would say [display](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/display) is sufficient, since its tag wiki reports it is about (among other thing) *the display(s) attached to a unix or linux machine*.